# Учебник по вебу

Tags: веб-программирование, документация

Подскажите хороший учебник по вебу для новичка. Мне нужно, чтобы там было написано, как все устроено и т.д. Нужен именно принцип работы, а не веб-языки! Обязательное условие - учебник должен быть бесплатным и его можно прочитать в интернете онлайн.

P.S Мне нужно создать сайт с нуля! (Возможно даже движок свой.)

Comment: Вам не нужно этого хотеть.

Comment: Это уже мое дело. Что хотеть, а что нет.

Comment: тут уже с десяток таких тем было

Comment: Это ничего не меняет. Да и вообще думаю тему надо закрыть, а то развели тут один флуд!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть книжки "основы алгоритмизации и программирования", "совершенный код" и книга "профессиональное программирование на php" (Шлосснейгл). Изучайте. Ещё б советовал какую-нибудь книгу или мануалы по апачу почитать, чтобы понимать чего такое mod_rewrite и прочие server-side прелести.
Удачи в изучении!!!

Answer (score 2):

Конкретизируйте ваш вопрос. Ваш интересует: "Как всё работает и почему"? Посмотрите:

- [каталог курсов](http://www.intuit.ru/courses.html),
- [введение в интернет-технологии](http://www.structuralist.narod.ru/it/internet/internet.htm),
- [введение в веб-технологии](http://www.webmasterwiki.ru/VvedenieVWebTexnologii)

для начала. Плюс, есть wikipedia, там много можно подчерпнуть.

UPD Если вам необходимо создать сайт с нуля, то план таков(после ознакомления с основами webа):

1. HTML 4,5
2. CSS 3
3. JavaScript (JQuery)
4. PHP4,5 (ещё очень много где используется, навряд ли скоро умрёт)

Это базовый набор. К моменту, когда всё будет изучено, будет ясно дальнейшее развитие. Python(Django) или Ruby on rails. Также поймёете что ближе— вёрстка или кодинг.

Comment: Я знаю все выше перечисленное. Кроме пхп. Его только недавно начал учить. И это все не то. Допустим мне нужно создать сайт с нуля. А я даже не знаю с чего начать. Ну написать код это понятно. А дальше?! Как связать файлы шаблона, сделать админку и т.д

Answer (score 0):

Очень хорошая книга по общим вопросам (далеко не только по HTTP!)

> HTTP: The Definitive Guide. David Gourley, Brian Totty, Marjorie Sayer, Sailu Reddy, Anshu Aggarwal

В сети она есть. На amazon.com можно найти и ознакомиться с оглавлением.

p.s.: Сайт с ее помощью вы вряд ли сделаете, но базовые принципы как что функционирует там описаны

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но мне нужна книга на русском)

Answer (score 0):

Учился по Лара Томпсон и Люк Веллинг, названия не помню. Жаль, что она устарела как "код", но для понимания всего происходящего очень понравилась.

Comment: Люк Веллинг, Лора Томсон.
Paзpaбoткa приложений c пoмoщью РНР и MySQL? Эта? Если да то это не то что мне нужно

Answer (score 0):

Читайте блоги и ресурсы посвященные созданию сайтов (спец. форумы и т.д.). Бесплатно и онлайн.

Comment: Можете дать линк? Сколько не искал в гугле нахожу только типа "Создай сайт за 3 минуты" и всякие примеры одностраничных сайтов на HTML

Comment: Начните с изучения основ html + css (htmlbook.ru, html.manual.ru, css.manual.ru). Потом ищите статьи и примеры по верстке сайтов. Например: csszengarden.com, alistapart.com, zeldman.com, mezoblue.com, webmascon.com, 456bereastreet.com. Много полезных статей, правда почти все на английском. Вот еще примеры верстки web-silver.ru/forum/html-css-javascript/9242-prakticheskie-sovety-po-vyorstke.html . Потом изучайте php+mysql+javascript. phpclub.ru, forum.dklab.ru, плюс довольно специфические форумы как crutop.nu, umaxforum.com

Comment: Вы, наверное, не читали, что написано выше. Я знаю html, css, JS, mysql. PHP в процессе изучения. Мне нужны все тонкости + все с нуля.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите видео уроки создания сайта с нуля на PHP от Евгения Попова  , там всё что вам нужно объясняться и про работу с базой и про создание шаблона и тд и тп.

Но да это не "Почитать онлайн"

Comment: Курс Е. Попова, насколько я успел его пролистать, демонстрирует общие основы языка, которые можно прочитать в любом учебнике и затем демонстрируется одно бездарно написанное приложение. Я говорю одно, потому что все остальные приложения его курса сделаны по образу и подобию первого. Т.е. афтар продемонстрировал яйцо и повертел его разными сторонами перед глазами восхищенной публики. Верите, что каждый оборот яйца вокруг оси научит вас чему-то новому? Я не верю!

Answer (score 0):

**Денис Колисниченко** 
**PHP 5/6 и MySQL 6**
Разработка Web-приложений